# How to force Cover block to use the full size image resolution

Tags: functions, images, block-editor, header-image

Is there anyway to force Cover block to use the full size image resolution?
It changes it based on the screen dimension and some times it gets so blurry which is awful!
Should I write some lines of code in function.php!?
PS: 2023 is my theme.
[This is the home page and if u check it with your mobile u will notice its bad image quality!](https://escapefromtehran.com/)